# Multiple database connections with sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo, sails-redis

It's possible to have a mysql connect for each registered and authenticated client ?

For example:

I need to have a different database for each client and I wonder if you can do this with the sailsjs.

Answer (score 0):

No sure but I don't think so, in `sailsjs` we have  :

`config/env/production.js`

```
models: {
      connection: 'someMysqlServer'
}
```

So its possible to choose only one DB :

```
someMysqlServer: {
   adapter: 'sails-mysql',
   host: 'YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
   user: 'YOUR_MYSQL_USER',
   password: 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD',
   database: 'YOUR_MYSQL_DB'
},
```

And it's not a good idea to create a db for each user.

why not do this in your conception? in one DB you can have all users information.